# For continuous and strictly increasing functions which are equal at the endpoints there is a point such that their derivatives are equal

Tags: derivatives

I have the following problem: Suppose $f,g$ are two functions which are continuous and strictly increasing in $[a,b]$, differentiable in $(a,b)$, and $g(a) = f(a)$ and $g(b) = f(b)$. Prove that there is a point $c \in (a,b)$ for which $g'(c) = f'(c)$.

Using the mean value theorem I proved that there are points $c_g,c_f \in (a,b)$ such that $g'(c_g) =f'(c_f)$. However, I'm stuck on how to prove that $c_g = c_f$. I assume that I need to use the property that $f$ and $g$ are both strictly increasing, but I don't know how to apply that to the derivatives.

Comment: Consider $h = g-f$ :)

Comment: What should I be looking for? Do I need to apply the MVT to $h$ instead?

Comment: If h = g-f, than h(a) = h(b) = 0.  So by MVT there is a point where h'(c) = 0.

Comment: Note that strictly increasing has nothing to do with it; agreement at the endpoints is all you need (by Rolle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @BrianO's (and @JohnMa's!) hint: if $h = g - f$, then $h(a) = h(b) = 0$ and if you can show that $h'(c) = 0$ for some point $c \in (a,b)$, then...

Comment: @JohnMa 's hint too though he removed it, he beat me to it — he was typing while I was still reading the question.